# How can i display curl results on an html page, using yesod?

Tags: haskell, curl, yesod

I want to post the results of a curl command within an html page,
using the yesod framework in haskell.
This is the code i have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes, MultiParamTypeClasses,
         TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Yesod
import Network.Curl
import Text.Blaze hiding (toMarkup)

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

url = "http://www.google.com/"
opts = [CurlFollowLocation True]

res=withCurlDo $ do
            curlGet url opts
            return ()

instance ToMarkup (IO a) where
toMarkup a = a

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler RepHtml
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|#{toMarkup res}|]

main :: IO ()
main = warpDebug 3000 HelloWorld
```

This code launches the server with the warning

```
Warning: No explicit method nor default method for `Text.Blaze.toMarkup'
In the instance declaration for `ToMarkup (IO a)'
```

and on pointing the web browser to

```
http://localhost:3000
```

it gives "Internal Server Error" along the above warning message as an HTML page.

I'm fairly new to Haskell and Yesod... could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong for `toMarkup` (it should be indented). However the types are still wrong. `toMarkup` should return a `Markup` instance and `curlGet` dumps the output to stdout, whereas you want to capture it and re-render it.

Try something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes, MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Yesod
import Network.Curl

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
      / HomeR GET
    |]

url = "http://www.google.com/"
opts = [CurlFollowLocation True]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR = do
    (code, res) <- liftIO $ curlGetString url opts        
    -- This doesn't work since Yesod HTML-escapes the content in the template
    -- defaultLayout [whamlet|#{res}|]
    return $ RepHtml $ toContent res

main :: IO ()
main = warpDebug 3000 HelloWorld
```

As an alternative to curl, you could also use the [*http-conduit* package](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/http-conduit). Import `Net.HTTP.Conduit` and you could write `getHomeR` as:

```
getHomeR = fmap (RepHtml . toContent) . liftIO $ simpleHttp "http://www.google.com"
```